# "Equivalence of opposite categories" synonymous with "dually equivalent categories"?

Tags: category-theory

Are the following statements four ways of saying exactly the same thing?
1. (Stating that) a category C and its opposite category C* (its dual) are *equivalent*.
2. C and C* are thus *self-dual* (by virtue of being opposite categories to each other, and being equivalent).
3. C and C* are thus *dually equivalent*.
4. C and C* thus constitute a "*duality of categories*".
In short, are "equivalence of opposite categories", "self-dual categories", and "dually equivalent categories", synonymous expressions ?

Comment: The first is presumably the definition of the second. I don't recall ever seeing "dually equivalent" or "duality of categories" (used this way). Saying $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal C^{op}$ are "dually equivalent" seems like not what you'd want, but rather you'd say $\mathcal C$ is dually equivalent to itself. At least that's how I'd expect that to be used. As for "duality of categories", my expectations would be that would refer to $(-)^{op}$ itself or some other kind of dualizing operation.

Comment: Thank you, Derek.  So if we say "C is dually equivalent to itself", as you suggest, is it the case that that carries the same meaning as saying "C is self-dual"?